# queryset in manytomany relation

Tags: postgresql, django-queryset

in this project we assign a badge to student in classroom.

```
class Badge(models.Model):
    klass = models.ForeignKey( # klass means classroom
        'klass.Class',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='badges',
        db_index=True,
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField( # the students in 'klass' that have this badge
        User,
        through='UserBadge',
        through_fields=('badge', 'user'),
    )
```

custom middle table for `users` ManyToMany field:

```
class UserBadge(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='taken_badges',
    )
    badge = models.ForeignKey(
        Badge,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='assigned_badges',
    )
        klass = models.ForeignKey( # this classroom is badge.klass
        'klass.Class',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='assigned_badges',
    )
```

i need to find all badge related to specific `user` and `klass` . so i can retrieve all badge for a specific student in specific classroom.

i tried :

```
Bagde.objects.filter(userbadge__user__id = student_id,userbadge__klass__id=klass_id)
```

and error is :
`Cannot resolve keyword 'userbadge' into field.`
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have set the `related_name` to `'assigned_badges'`, you should implement the filter as:

```
Bagde.objects.filter(
    assigned_badges__user__id=student_id,
    assigned_badges__klass__id=klass_id
)
```

Comment: thank you master . i found another way too `student.badge_set.filter(klass=klass)` if possible let e know witch one of this way are faster?

Comment: The first one, given you did not fetch the `student` before. Since with `student.badge_set.filter(..)` you thus first need to fetch the `student` object with a query. The query itself (so the `student.badge_set.filter(..)` itself will result in an equivalent query, so these are the same), but fetching the student of course results in an extra query.